# What is fault bucket and should I care?

Tags: windows, windows-event-log

As part of our regular preventative maintenance, we check the event logs on the workstations in our network for serious issues (e.g. diskperf errors). Some workstations commonly have a critical error where the explanation is "Fault bucket" followed by some number. Can anybody explain what this means? Does it really point to some critical problem that we should care about? Anything we can do about it so that it no longer shows up?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A fault bucket identification number is a number assigned by the system to identify specific types of errors. This number is used by Microsoft to identify a particular program error when you send an error report.

If you get a "this program has encountered a problem and needs to close" type error, click the 'Send error report' button, and you may get a resolution to the problem.

You could also try Googling the fault bucket number to see if you can identify the source of the errors.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a more specific error, logged just before the fault bucket one?  If so, try fixing whatever's causing it and see if it goes away.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, what you want to do is figure out what's CAUSING the exception or unusual condition.  Microsoft Windows is a complex conglomerate of software and problems can have many possible sources.  Once you find out what's CAUSING the problem, then maybe, just maybe, you can do something to stop the bad stuff.

Questions about errors show responsibility on your part, and you are to be commended.  However, owing to Microsoft's strong desire to offer the lowest acceptable quality to maximize profits, there really isn't any meaning relating to the number you see.  You could literally ask every member on the Microsoft tech support team for help, and they'll just tell you to reinstall the entire operating system.

One might imagine that Microsoft would want their operating system to use state-of-the-art technology, such that problems from one area can be easily diagnosed by another team that specializes in a different section.  Not so!  As long as warm bodies continue typing (and as long as many of these doing so are outside the high pay rates of the continental USA), everything is fine.  What's most critical is that Windows works well as a new computer.

Is your computer old?  Then, the obvious solution is to upgrade to Windows 10.  Why?  Because of insecurities!  Who would want an insecure computer?  Plus, the Windows 10 system is so much better.  It's just a side-effect that Microsoft would prefer that all the previous operating systems would simply disappear, since this would increase their profits to an intoxicating degree.

To summarize and in conclusion, you will want to find out what those mysterious numbers mean.  When you do that, you will be in a much better position to figure out what is going on.  At that point, you will pretty much have the problem solved.